# Accessing Content Builder via SOAP Webservices

Tags: marketing-cloud, webservices

I am using classic builder for template in my integration using SOAP API , Now Exact target launch new Content Builder functionality , Is it possible to get Content Builder using SOAP API get the template html code over there (in integrated system).

Answer (score 1):

As of this moment, content builder only works with the REST API. There are plans to bring SOAP functionality to it in the future.

> Marketing Cloud has a new model for storing, finding, managing,
>   creating, sharing and distributing all content-related objects. You
>   can access the objects created with the new Content Builder tools
>   using the REST API. Your existing SOAP API integrations will only
>   function with the Classic tools in the user interface. Updates to the
>   SOAP API to support the new Content Builder tools are expected in
>   2017.

References:

- [Content Builder API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm)
- [SOAP Web Service Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/web_service_guide.htm)